# Problem with "Include file search path" in Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I've installed Delphi 2010 and Quick report 2010 recently. the problem is finding DCU files of  the quick report packages when i'm trying to compile the project although the path of the installed package of Quick Report has been added to "Include file search path" of resource compile. 
How i can specify the path of installed packages in new version of Delphi when that doesn't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that the path is already present in the compiler search path (not resource compiler!) for the project or the library path of the IDE.

Answer (score 2):

In Delphi 2010:

Go to **Options | Environment Options | Delphi Options | Library - Win32**

And add DCU or PAS files path of QuickReport to "**Library Path**".